# My Django app won't detect settings.py, and won't detect SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my Django app.

For some reason it won't detect settings.py nor SECRET_KEY.

First, here is my structure of the project dir

```
C:.
│   manage.py
│
├───Accounts
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │       login.html
│   │       signup.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│          omitted
│
├───Blog
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───templates
├───Learning
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───templates
├───static
│   │   compiled_sass.css
│   │   compiled_sass.css.map
│   │
│   └───sass-styles
│       │   styles.sass
│       │
│       ├───src
│       │       omitted
│       │
│       └───static
│               omitted
│
└───tf
    │   local_settings.py
    │   settings.py
    │   TODO.md
    │   urls.py
    │   wsgi.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───templates
    └───__pycache__
            omitted
```

Now, when running I get `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

That's how my settings.py look like

```
"""
Django settings for tf project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""


import os
from ..Accounts.models import CustomUser

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'some key which is there'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Accounts',
    'Blog',
    'Learning',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tf.urls'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Techfluent.Accounts.models.CustomUser'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['tf\\templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tf.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '*******',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..\\Techfluent\\static\\')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '\\static\\'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL ='\\media\\'

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    raise Exception("A local_settings.py file is required")
```

Can you all help me out? I am going nuts in here trying to solve this for few hours now.

If it helps, I started the project on MacOS, and then I cloned it to my Windows. It's Django 2.2, Python3.7.

I am also apparently getting ModuleNotFoundError because it couldn't find 'tf' module.

Comment: are you using settings.py or local_settings.py while running your project?

Comment: Your `settings.py` looks fine to me. Given that it's giving you a ModuleNotFoundError I believe its do with your project structure. Can you confirm if it conforms to this https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure.html

Comment: @danish_wani I am using settings.py where I am importing local_settings.py

Comment: can you share local_settings.py ?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 seems to me it is

Comment: @danish_wani 
```import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

SECRET_KEY = 'another_secret_key'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'techfluentdb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'somepassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}```

Comment: local_settings.py looks fine to me, I guess there is something wrong the project structure. Is this hosted on any VCS? or you simply copied it from MAC to Windows?

Comment: It was copied from MacOS to Windows. Is that the issuse?

Comment: I suspect change in operating system could be an issue. But did it run on macOS?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 it did. What I ended up doing is I created a new project on Windows

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up doing, is I ended up starting a completely new project, and copied and pasted files from the old one, and it works.